# Get json data with UnityWebRequest with API

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, http-get

I am trying to access JSON data from a website and I can easily do it with command prompt. I receive the data with the following command:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token 1a2a3b4c5d" https://sampleweb.com/api/v1/sites/
```

However I cannot access it with Unity, I am adding the header request as well as the API key, yet I receive authorization error. What am I doing wrong here?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;

public class GetAPI : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const string URL = "https://sampleweb.com/api/v1/sites/";
    private const string API_KEY = "1a2a3b4c5d";

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            GenerateRequest();
        }
    }

    public void GenerateRequest()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ProcessRequest(URL));
    }

    private IEnumerator ProcessRequest(string uri)
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
        {
            request.SetRequestHeader("Authorization: Token", API_KEY);

            yield return request.SendWebRequest();

            if (request.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.Log("Error: " + request.error);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Received: " + request.downloadHandler.text);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried "Token 1a2a3b4c5d" as the header data as you showed in the curl example?

Comment: Was going to say you didn’t send token. So it won’t know what to do with it

Comment: Change `private const string API_KEY = "1a2a3b4c5d";` to `private const string API_KEY = "Token 1a2a3b4c5d";`

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you i got it now. I had to omit ```:``` and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The part before the `:` is the header name, the second part the value.

You want to set the header `Authorization` to the value `Token + SOMEKEY` so it should rather be

```
request.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", $"Token {API_KEY}");
```

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately this does not work. I get an unauthorized error message.